# if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[image][name])) is not working

Tags: php

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[image][name]))
{
    $row_PID = $_REQUEST['PID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_image where PID='".$str_PID."'";
    $row    =   mysql_query($sql, $conn);

    while($getPID=mysql_fetch_array($row))
    {
        $PID = $getPID['PID'];
        $sqldelete ="delete from tbl_image where PID ='".$PID."'";
        tep_db_query($sqldelete,$conn);
    }

    while(list($key,$value) = each($_FILES[image][name]))
    {
        if(!empty($value)) 
        {   
            $filename = $value;  // filename stores the value
            $add = "../upload/portfolio/$filename";  // upload directory path is set
            copy($_FILES[image][tmp_name][$key], $add);
            chmod("$add",0777); 
        } 

        $query="insert into tbl_image (ImageID,PID,ImagePath,DateCreated,LastUpdate) values ('','$str_PID','$filename',now(),now())";
        tep_db_query($query, $conn);
    }
}
```

I not access `if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[image][name]))` this condition

Comment: Please improve the post quality

Comment: You've got serious security problems here: SQL injection, directory traversal, no filetype checking... don't put this code on the net, or it will be possible for anyone who can access it to execute code of their choice on your server. Making file-upload safe is **hard**.

Comment: According to your question the code inside the condition is unnecessary. This will move someones attention from the condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES[image][name]))
```

Does not work because `$_FILES['image']['name']` does not contain a path to a file on disk. This is clearly explained in [the PHP manual](http://php.net/is_uploaded_file):

> For proper working, the function is_uploaded_file() needs an argument
>   like `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']`, - the name of the uploaded file
>   on the client's machine `$_FILES['userfile']['name']` does not work.

That and you are not quoting your array keys so they will be evaluated as PHP constants rather than strings. You should be using:

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))
```

Note the apostrophes (single quotes) surrounding each array key and the corrected variable.

Comment: i understand your ans but it is also not use                         if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']))